# Updating service reference: port 80 in use

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

I'm trying to update service references in Visual studio and prompt keeps saying Port '80' is in use. 
noted things: I'm using IIS Express when running my silverlight program.
I have checked http://localhost:80 to see what is hijacking port 80 and it returns Not Found. 
From win10 resource monitor I see that system is using port 80. No IIS service found running in task manager. I can start the service and use it normally just without the service reference update. I have also restarted both pc and vs for several times.

Edit: I have no full IIS installed: When checking from windows features there are nothing checked on internet information services.

Comment: the service is running on some 8k+ port and so is the IIS Express when it's started

Comment: You need to find out _what_ is causing a web server to try to start on port 80. Is the web service inside the same solution, in a Web Application? Visual Studio will then start hosting that project when adding or updating a service reference. Is this Web Application set to start using IIS Express, on port 80? Then change that project's port.

Comment: try netstat -ab .. should show you whats using port 80

Comment: Sorry for badly placed words: Resource Monitor states that program "system" is using the port 80. netstat -ab on the other hand says "Can not obtain ownership information". When I try to findout the what is using port and go with browser to localhost:80 port page is returned as Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is usually used by HTTP requests and it is not advisable to use a commonly used port for another service. It would be better to choose a port that is not in use by any other program/service and is not used/reserved for anything. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers for a list of commonly used and reserved ports.

> The port numbers in the range from 0 to 1023 are the well-known ports or system ports. They are used by system processes that provide widely used types of network services

Don't choose any of them to avoid problems for your users. So if you have control of the service, change port to something else and it should work.

Comment: This is a blanket statement that is not helpful towards OP's specific scenario. Browsers also don't use port 80 to listen.

Comment: I read the question as if OP tries to set the service to run on port 80. And suggested to change port. If that is not the case then I agree that this is not helpful.

Comment: I read it more, that OP trying to update the service references. Do you known WCF?

Comment: The error message OP receives is "Port '80' is in use. I created a WCF project and hosted it on port 80, all is ok. But when adding service reference to another project, I get the same exact error message as OP! When changing the WCF project to another port I can add it as a service reference. So I can reproduce the error and the solution is to change to port for the WCF project. Might still be something else but this solves a problem that can cause that exact error message.

Comment: Well the app/system I'm developing is part of company's  system and therefor can't change the port since other parts can't find service on the wrong port. Tried using different port on service reference update but that didnt do the trick either since coulnt find references

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out I had SQL Server Reporting Service installed (which I shouldn't even have had).  In any case after removing it from the programs updating services where successful.